# Class implementing UITableViewDataSource is always null

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview that should have its delegate and datasource properties set from `InsertIntoTableViewDelegate` and `InsertIntoTableViewDatasource` Classes respectively. However, my `InsertIntoTableViewDatasource` class always returns `null`.

Here is the code:

```
class InsertIntoTableViewDatasource: NSObject,UITableViewDataSource {

    var data:NSMutableArray

    init(With data: NSMutableArray){
        self.data = data
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rowCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row] as? String
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here is the how the tableview is being set:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Testing"
    tableView.dataSource = InsertIntoTableViewDatasource(With: data)
    tableView.delegate = InsertIntoTableViewDelegate()
}
```

**Why is this the case?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableView` does not retain its datasource, so your datasource is getting deallocated as soon as your `viewDidLoad` function ends.

You need to hold a reference to your datasource as a property in your view controller.  Same thing with the delegate.

Comment: Out of curiosity do you know why it doesn't hold its datasource?

Comment: Its common to make the view controller itself the datasource, so you would get a retain cycle from the view controller and tableview retaining each other.  Same reason objects usually don't retain their delegates.